# VAR model and AR model

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

When does a bivariate VAR(2) model equal to a combination of two separate univariate AR(2
) models?

Answer (score 1):

When you have something like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1t}\\y_{2t}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11,1}&0\\0&a_{22,1}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1t-1}\\y_{2t-1}
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11,2}&0\\0&a_{22,2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y_{1t-2}\\y_{2t-2}
\end{pmatrix}+
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{1t}\\u_{2t}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
they will be equivalent.